# XtraReport print only select rows C#

Tags: c#, winforms, xtrareport

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykefh.png)I have checkbox in datagridview, and I want after checked print (XtraReport ) only checked row in datagridview. Now all print from datagridview.

Comment: Can you show bit more of your own working ?

Comment: Yes, Im now add new picture.

Comment: is datagridview is standard dotnet winforms grid? you may show how do you generate report layout

Comment: Yes, added new picture. I only called report and print all. I want print only checked in checkbox(datagridview column).

Comment: i can't find, how do you configure xtrareport layout?

Comment: @k0st1x If you know, I can send my project and you can see.

Comment: yep, share it via google drive or onedrive or any other service

Comment: the file is not public

Comment: as i described in the answer, you should update "materialFlatButton8_Click" method so aggregate selected rows ids into int-array and pass it into report parameter before calling "report.ShowPreview()".

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But still it’s hard for me.

Comment: 1) create multivalue parameter 2) add filter based on parameter 3) pass parameter value before preview

Comment: It seems very simple, public if I succeed. Thank you, I want to deal with the reports.

Comment: When the report opens, a filter comes out and I enter a string? it finds that string and prints it. But I'm still not over checkbox.

Comment: you can share an updated project with modifications to sync vision :)

Answer (score 0):

to print only selected rows, you may assign a [XtraReport.FilterString](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReportBase.FilterString) and create a invisible [multivalue parameter](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/9998/detailed-guide-to-devexpress-reporting/shape-report-data/use-report-parameters/multi-value-report-parameters) to pass the checked ids to it.
so the report layout may have the

```cs
.FilterString = "ID in (?filterParameters)"
```

where the 'filterParameters' is a parameter name.
and before report print preview is shown you may pass the parameter value like

```cs
report.Parameters["filterParameters"].Value = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
new ReportPrintTool(report).ShowRibbonPreviewDialog();
```

Comment: Thx bro, but i added the checkbox to datagridview as a column, i don't have it in xtrareport as filterstirng.

Comment: yes, i see that. so you need manualy from your code filter items that was checked in grid and pass rows id to report parameter, as i mentioned in answer. you can show your code here, how you tried to get checked rows from gridview.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)  //1
                {
                  bool isCellChecked = Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);  //2
                    if (isCellChecked == true)
                    {

                        var allCheckedRows = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()   //3
                                   .Where(row => (bool?)row.Cells[0].Value == true)
                                   .ToList();

Comment: //1  going through datagridview
//2  if checked then true
//3 stores all (true) values in ToList();
How to print only those values in XtraReport?

Comment: to filter values that are checked on grid, you should get IDs from your your "allCheckedRows" as int[] and pass it to xtrareport parameter. you may try to apply steps from answer and report your progress here in comments.

Comment: I haven't set it up yet.